# Add folder & all contents to bundle via CM?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, bundles

Can you add a folder and all of its contents to a bundle?  It looks like when you insert a folder into a bundle only the folder is added, not all the items under it.  We have a complicated folder structure and I'd rather not go thru  each folder & add all the contents.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by performing an **Advanced Search** on the parent Folder, and then adding all of the results to your bundle.

If you just want Components, and not sub-Folders, then you can filter these out using the **Types** Advanced Search option to just return Components.

The setting that you probably want are:

- Searching term: *
- Also search in sub-sections: Ticked
- Content type: Components
- Number of results: All

You may want to look at my blog post from earlier in the year about [Publishing Tridion Folders](http://blog.stage-two.com/2014/06/02/publishing-tridion-folders/) - Only instead of publishing the results of the search, you will want to add them to you Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest - from an editor's point of view - would be to use the Event System to "grab" the components whenever a folder is added to a bundle. Could become tricky if you ever want to actually include just the folder.

The `BundleSaveEventArgs` events have a property named "ItemsAdded" (and "ItemsRemoved"), so you could use this to figure out when to kick in and add more items to the Bundle.